# Spotfire over function with previous and category

Tags: function, spotfire, tibco

For a giving row, I would like to calculate the previous date in the table on the same category. See example below:

| date | category | expected_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 03/02/2023 | A |  |
| 06/02/2023 | A | 03/02/2023 |
| 07/02/2023 | A | 06/02/2023 |
| 03/02/2023 | B |  |
| 04/02/2023 | B | 03/02/2023 |
| 06/02/2023 | B | 03/02/2023 |
| 07/02/2023 | B | 06/02/2023 |
| 03/02/2023 | C |  |
| 07/02/2023 | C | 03/02/2023 |

How could I get the expected dates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating an intermediate node using the rank.

First calculated column:

```
[tmp_rank] = DenseRank([date],[category])
```

Second calculated column:

```
First([date]) over Intersect(Previous([tmp_rank]),[category])
```

Be careful to not directly use `Previous([date])` because it is not calculated in the current category but globally for the whole dataset.
If categories do not all have the same dates, empty cells will be generated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a "row_id" for each row using the expression `RowId()`
2. Then, using "row_id", create a calculated column "expected" which grabs the previous date of a category.

   `Min([date]) OVER (Intersect([category],Previous([row_id])))`

Output table:

[image]

Comment: Good idea but the if rows are not ordered by date it does not works. Let's add a last row `date`=02/02/2023 and `category`="A" to be convinced.

Comment: As OP didn't mention sorting as one of the criteria, I haven't taken that into account. If that has to be considered then your solution makes sense. I would upvote yours. Thanks!